# Access the remote Bean in A GlassFish4.0 from B GlassFish 4.0 error javaee7

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I want to access an `@Remote` bean in GlassFish Server 4.0 from another one. I have tried many ways but no one works.

```
//This is the remote Interface For server A and client B:
@Remote
public interface SayHelloBeanRemote extends Serializable{
 public void test(String name);
}

//Impl for Client B:
@Stateless
public class SayHelloBean implements SayHelloBeanRemote {

  @Override
  public void test(String name) {
     System.out.println("nihao"+name);
  }
}
```

first I write a method in the JSF managed bean :

```
public void test() throws NamingException {

 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
 props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
 props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
 props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.1.104");
 props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
 InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
 SayHelloBeanRemote testRmi = (SayHelloBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("java:global/EJBRm/rmi/NewSessionBean");
 testRmi.test("xx");
 System.out.println("k开始连接.....................");
}
```

this is the error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed
>   for 'java:global/EJBRmi/rmi/NewSessionBean' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700,
>   java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=192.168.1.104,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root
>   exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: rmi]

then I try to use the `sun-web.xml` to configure the app:

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <ejb-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>RemoteEJBName</ejb-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:<servername or IP>:3700#java:global/Rmi_ejb   /FooClassImpl!com.test.foo.FooClass</jndi-name>
  </ejb-ref>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

I use tag:

```
@EJB( name="TheRef") SayHelloBeanRemote testRmi;
```

but the injection failed.

So I need your help, give a right way to access the EJB between A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Java EE 7 and both your server and client are within the application server, there is no need to do a manual lookup - you'd only need that when having a standalone java client which needs to access an EJB (see my example in [my answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582575/ejb-3-1-problems-with-jndi-stand-alone-application-with-glassfish-4/24626593#24626593)).

If you access one EJB from another managed component, just use the injection mechanism. See chapter "[Accessing Enterprise Beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-intro004.htm#GIPJF)" from Java EE tutorial.